# Construct an array spacing proportional to a function or other array

Tags: python, algorithm, numeric, numerical-methods

I have a function (`f` : black line) which varies sharply in a specific, small region (derivative `f'` : blue line, and second derivative `f''` : red line).  I would like to integrate this function numerically, and if I distribution points evenly (in log-space) I end up with fairly large errors in the sharply varying region (near `2E15` in the plot).

**How can I construct an array spacing such that it is very well sampled in the area where the second derivative is large (i.e. a sampling frequency proportional to the second derivative)?**

I happen to be using python, but I'm interested in a general algorithm.

---

*Edit:

**1)** It would be nice to be able to still control the number of sampling points (at least roughly).

**2)** I've considered constructing a probability distribution function shaped like the second derivative and drawing randomly from that --- but I think this will offer poor convergence, and in general, it seems like a more deterministic approach should be feasible.*

[image]

Comment: Did you mean red and blue the other way around? The red one looks like the derivative.

Comment: @Trengot no, I'm sure red is the second derivative and blue the first.

Comment: Ok, I guess the log scale threw me.

Comment: If you don't get good results here, you might also try [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'd try Computational Science before Computer Science.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `f''` is a `NumPy` `array`, you could do the following

```
# Scale these deltas as you see fit
deltas = 1/f''
domain = deltas.cumsum()
```

To account only for order of magnitude swings, this could be adjusted as follows...

```
deltas = 1/(-np.log10(1/f''))
```

Comment: Thanks @Alex, this was similar to my first idea - but I'm finding that it leads to wild variance in the total number of points (who cares about a factor of 2, but the number of points varies by more than an order of magnitude with very minor changes to the normalization).  I think something like this could work, but needs much more fine tuning.

Comment: Hmm would taking the log help?

Comment: Hmmmm, so scaling/ taking more logs doesn't get you a good answer?

Answer (score 1):

I'm just spitballing here ... (as I don't have time to try this out for real)...

Your data looks (roughly) linear on a log-log plot (at least, each segment seems to be... So, I might consider doing a sort-of integration in log-space.

```
log_x = log(x)
log_y = log(y)
```

Now, for each of your points, you can get the slope (and intercept) in log-log space:

```
rise = np.diff(log_y)
run = np.diff(log_x)
slopes = rise / run
```

And, similarly, the the intercept can be calculated:

```
# y = mx + b
# :. b = y - mx
intercepts = y_log[:-1] - slopes * x_log[:-1]
```

Alright, now we have a bunch of (straight) lines in log-log space.  But, a straight line in log-log space, corresponds to `y = log(intercept)*x^slope` in real space.  We can integrate that easily enough:  `y = a/(k+1) x ^ (k+1)`, so...

```
def _eval_log_log_integrate(a, k, x):
    return np.log(a)/(k+1) * x ** (k+1)

def log_log_integrate(a, k, x1, x2):
    return _eval_log_log_integrate(a, k, x2) - _eval_log_log_integrate(a, k, x1)

partial_integrals = []
for a, k, x_lower, x_upper in zip(intercepts, slopes, x[:-1], x[1:]):
    partial_integrals.append(log_log_integrate(a, k, x_lower, x_upper))

total_integral = sum(partial_integrals)
```

<sup>You'll want to check my math -- It's been a while since I've done this sort of thing :-)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your response, but this is a method of numerical integration --- I'm looking for a method of refining my sample spacing.  I don't want to rely the even spacing of `x` or `log_x`.

Comment: @zhermes -- Right, I get that.  My point is that with this sort of data, you could likely use logarithmcally spaces values (on the x-axis) for the bins since the interpolating function is much smarter than using a simple simpson's rule or something of that sort.

Answer (score 0):

**1) The Cool Approach**

At the moment I implemented an 'adaptive refinement' approach [inspired by hydrodynamics techniques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_mesh_refinement).  I have a function which I want to sample, `f`, and I choose some initial array of sample points `x_i`.  I construct a "sampling" function `g`, which determines where to insert new sample points.

In this case I chose `g` as the slope of `log(f)` --- since I want to resolve rapid changes ***in log space***.  I then divide the span of `g` into `L=3` refinement levels.  If `g(x_i)` exceeds a refinement level, that span is subdivided into `N=2` pieces, those subdivisions are added into the samples and are checked against the next level.  This yields something like this:

The **solid grey** line is the function I want to sample, and the **black crosses** are my initial sampling points.
The **dashed grey** line is the derivative of the log of my function.
The **colored dashed** lines are my 'refinement levels'
The **colored crosses** are my refined sampling points.

This is all shown in log-space.

[image]

**2) The Simple Approach**

After I finished (1), I realized that I probably could have just chosen a maximum spacing in in `y`, and choose `x`-spacings to achieve that.  Similarly, just divide the function evenly in `y`, and find the corresponding `x` points.... The results of this are shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be to split the x-axis-array into three parts and use different spacing for each of them. It would allow you to maintain the total number of points and also the required spacing in different regions of the plot. For example:

```
x = np.linspace(10**13, 10**15, 100)
x = np.append(x, np.linspace(10**15, 10**16, 100))
x = np.append(x, np.linspace(10**16, 10**18, 100))
```

You may want to choose a better spacing based on your data, but you get the idea.